# TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii, datepicker

I am using Yii Framework to develop an application. I am using

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    $('.date-picker').datepicker();
    
});
```

everywhere it is running, but when I am placing it in index.php view file, then it is giving me the following error in firefox console:

> TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function
>
> $('.date-picker').datepicker();

I have search the above error everywhere but no solutions are applicable in my criteria from stackoverflow, and other blogs for this query.

Thanks

Comment: The datepicker plugin JS isn't included or has a bad path.

Comment: ru sure that u have included the lib for datepicker ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to include jquery library files in your view page. I had the same problem two weeks ago,but when i called it separetely my problem got solved.

```
<?php
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('jquery');
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('jquery.ui');

Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile(Yii::app()->baseUrl .'/js/jquery.ui.datepicker.js'); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

The source of your error is most probably the **noConflict()** setting for jQuery. Here's the reasoning from [Wordpress Function Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers):

> The jQuery library included with WordPress is set to the **noConflict()**
>   mode (see [wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6.1/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js#L3)). This is to prevent
>   compatibility problems with other JavaScript libraries that WordPress
>   can link.
>
> In the **noConflict()** mode, the global $ shortcut for jQuery is not
>   available.

You just have to substitute `$` for `jQuery` and your code will work.

Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.date-picker').datepicker();
});
```

Or, you could continue using `$` if you pass it in the function, like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.date-picker').datepicker();
});
```

Comment: I guess that can't be the actual problem.

Comment: I have done this before asking this question here. I have used noconflict and jQuery instead of "$", but no effect :(

Comment: Sorry it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

**`Yii Framework`** *don't provide default datepicker*.  You must either use any of the extensions for datepicker.

Check [datepicker extension for yii framework](http://www.yiiframework.com/extensions/?tag=datepicker).  Also check 
[jQuery-ui datepicker in Yii framework](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/438/jquery-ui-datepicker/)